# xlsx library not working after moving angular-nodejs app from development to production server

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, server

I am trying to read an Excel file and get Excel sheet rows to a variable. I am using the xlsx library for that. The app is working in the development environment. But it is not working in the production server and shows the following error in the browser console.

```
ERROR Error: Unknown Namespace: http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types
    at parse_ct (xlsx.mjs:5198:34)
    at parse_zip (xlsx.mjs:23227:12)
    at read_zip (xlsx.mjs:23757:9)
    at readSync (xlsx.mjs:23828:69)
    at Module.readSync (xlsx.mjs:23804:79)
    at fileReaderA.onload (institute-applicants-daham-pasal.component.ts:327:24)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:27450:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:139:47)
```

This is my Angular function.

```
   onSecAFileChange(event: any, fileUploadA: any) {
        const fileA = event.files[0];
    
        const fileReaderA = new FileReader();
        fileReaderA.onload = (e: any) => {
          const data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
          const workbook = XLSX.read(e.target.result, {type: 'array'});
          const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
          const rows: any = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {header: 1, defval: ''});
        };
        fileReaderA.readAsArrayBuffer(fileA);
    }
```

The error occurred on line:

```
const workbook = XLSX.read(e.target.result, {type: 'array'});
```